# Jackson: deserialize JSON with XML-like lists

Tags: json, jackson

A service I don't control is sending me JSON that looks like this when there is one item:

```
{ items: {
     item: { ... }
}
```

... like this when there is no item:

```
{ items: null }
```

... and like this when there are two or more items:

```
 { items: {
    item: [
        { ... }, 
        { ... }
    ]
    }
 }
```

I believe this is because the service was designed to produce XML like this:

```
  <items>
       <item>....</item>
       <item>....</item>
  </items>
```

... and has thrown the results at an XML->JSON convertor without paying much attention to the result.

Using Jackson, I can handle the "sometimes null, sometimes object, sometimes array" issue in Jackson by configuring my ObjectMapper with `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY`.

I can handle the two-layer structure by defining an `Items` class with a field `List<Item> item`.

However, the Items class is only there as a sop to the weird JSON format. Other than by writing a whole custom deserializer, can I persuade Jackson to deserialize to an object *as if* the structure was:

```
{ items: [ { ... }, { ... } ] }
```

?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a root object which contains `Items` property. In this case you can use  `@JsonUnwrapped` annotation. See below class:

```
class Root {

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Items items = new Items();

    public Items getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Items items) {
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Simple usage:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Items items = new Items();
items.setItem(Arrays.asList(new Item(), new Item()));

Root wrapper = new Root();
wrapper.setItems(items);

String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(wrapper);
System.out.println(json);
```

Above program prints:

```
{"item":[{"name":"X"},{"name":"X"}]}
```

Comment: Thanks - This is what I want, only backwards. It shows how to serialize to a sane format. I want to deserialize JSON that's weird, to a sane object.

Comment: Deserializing works as well. You can do it in this way: `objectMapper.readValue(json, Root.class);`. Could you try?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the easiest way to handle mapping is to reflect structure of data format in your POJO structure. So in this case, you would add one functionally unnecessary, but mapping-wise necessary, property:

```
public class POJO {
    public ItemHolder items;

    // might want convenience method for Java access, but not with getter name
    public List<Item> items() {
       return (items == null) ? null : items.item;
    }
} 
public class ItemHolder {
    public List<Item> item;
}
```

and you do still also need to enable `DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` to handle mapping from single `Item` into `List<Item>`.

But perhaps the other answer of using `@JsonUnwrapped` also helps; it is another option.